# Where formatting data ? Model ? Controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, model, controller, formatting

I need to format data to use them after MySQL request.

Format date (using date library), sort and arrange data (using loop) etc.

Php example (CodeIgniter framework):

```
$result = $query->result_array();
$data = array();
foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key]['date'] = px_date_time_format($result[$key]['date'], 'fr');       
    if ($value['id_parent'] == 0) {
        $data[$value['id']] = $result[$key];
    }
}

foreach($result as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['id_parent'] != 0) {
        $data[$value['id_parent']]['children'][$value['id']] = $value;  
    }
}

return $data;
```

Where should I format this data? In my Model or my Controller?

Comment: You are clearly expecting "in model" answer. But that would be completely wrong. Even worse then the "in controller" version, because that COULD be true, if someone is implementing MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2):

In the view.

View in MVC design pattern is the part which is responsible for presentation logic. It create the response, that browser (assuming you are talking about adaptation of MVC for web) receives.

View requests data from model layer and, based on data, that it receives, and state previously set by controller, decides what response should it produce. I can be either HTML *(composed from multiple templates)* JSON, XML or even just a HTTP header.

Controller deals with user's input and model layer contains the business logic.

Comment: Not in the view! I need to change the structure of data which is return by MySQL so really not in the view!

Comment: @tilix in a correctly implemented MVC pattern the views request data directly from model layer. Therefore, the formating of data happens in the view, before said view starts binding data to different templates.

Comment: I just edited my question to show you why I can't do that in the view.

Comment: @tilix: You clearly seems to miss the point of the MVC pattern. Model is responsible for the heavy lifting, getting data from the different sources, and bringing them to the application memory. The Controller is responsible for user interaction, it is the one which requests the correct models for the job. The View is the one responsible for taking the raw data, and making it into something presentable. Hence, your question falls into the View category. You asked for the correct solution. This is it.

Comment: if this operation is repeated in more than one view, you should create an appropriate template for these lines

Comment: But I need to use this data in different controllers and views...
So either data are formated in model, or I create helper to format.

Comment: Since in CodeIgniter (which you said, you are using) you do not have real views, the best option is to put this operation in view helper. Formating of output it part of presentation logic.